# Join using Criteria API without foreign constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I'm really new to the Criteria API and I do not know how I can create a join query for the following situation. I already looked into the Oracle documentation of the Criteria API, but I could not make the examples work.

Say you have the following two tables in your database.

```
Item                                     Export
----------------------------             ---------------------------
| ItemId    | DateUpdated  |             | ItemId     | ExportDate |
----------------------------             ---------------------------
| 1         | 02/02/2016   |             | 1          | 02/02/2016 |
----------------------------             ---------------------------
| 2         | 03/02/2016   |             | 2          | 03/02/2016 |
----------------------------             ---------------------------
| 3         | 06/02/2016   |             | 3          | 05/02/2016 |
----------------------------             ---------------------------
| 4         | 07/02/2016   |             
----------------------------
```

The corresponding entity classes are exact representations of the tables.

The query should join `Item` with `Export`, but there is no foreign key from `Export.ItemId` to `Item.ItemId`. Further, as a result the query should select `Item` with `ItemId` 3, because `Export.ExportDate` is before `Item.DateAdded`, and `Item` with `ItemId` 4, because the id is not in `Export`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you need a formal key relationship in order to join two entity classes in Hibernate.  Check out any tutorial on joining in Hibernate and you should be able to modify your entity classes accordingly.

Comment: Foreign key is only used to check constraints when inserting, deleting or updating, it doesn't anything for optimizing, it's mostly to prevent human error. You really need indexes, not foreign keys and proper relation definition in your hibernate models.